# Invert boolean variable

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to try simple script

```
flag=false
while !$flag
do
   read x
   if [ "$x" -eq "true" ]
   then
     flag=true
   fi
   echo "${x} : ${flag}"
done
```

But when I run it, if I type `true`, I will see that `x="true"` and `flag="true"`, but the cycle doesn't end. What is wrong with the script? How can I properly invert a boolean variable?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108249/bash-scripting-boolean-variable-not-working-properly/8108301#8108301

Comment: It is very dangerious to execute a variable.  First ensure your script sets it.  and second ensure that the commands 'true' and 'false' really produce a true and false exist status.  Someone may pass your script a 'exported function' call 'true'!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are two errors in your script. The first is that you need a space between `!` and `$flag`, otherwise the shell looks for a command called `!$flag`. The second error is that `-eq` is for integer comparisons, but you're using it on a string. Depending on your shell, either you'll see an error message and the loop will continue forever because the condition `[ "$x" -eq "true" ]` cannot be true, or every non-integer value will be treated as 0 and the loop will exit if you enter any string (including `false`) other than a number different from 0.

While `! $flag` is correct, it's a bad idea to treat a string as a command. It would work, but it would be very sensitive to changes in your script, since you'd need to make sure that `$flag` can never be anything but `true` or `false`. It would be better to use a string comparison here, like in the test below.

```
flag=false
while [ "$flag" != "true" ]
do
   read x
   if [ "$x" = "true" ]
   then
     flag=true
   fi
   echo "${x} : ${flag}"
done
```

There's probably a better way to express the logic you're after. For example, you could make an infinite loop and break it when you detect the termination condition.

```
while true; do
  read -r x
  if [ "$x" = "true" ]; then break; fi
  echo "$x: false"
done
```

Comment: With the `[` builtin of `ksh`, `[ x -eq y ]` return true if the `x` arithmetic expression resolves to the same number as the `y` arithmetic expression so for instance `x=2 true=1+1 ksh -c '[ x -eq true ] && echo yes'` would output yes.

Answer (score 15):

While there are no Boolean variables in Bash, it is very easy to emulate them using arithmetic evaluation.

```
flag= # False
flag=0 # False
flag=1 # True (actually any integer number != 0 will do, but see remark below about toggling)
flag="some string" # Maybe False (make sure that the string isn't interpreted as a number)

if ((flag)) # Test for True
then
  : # do something
fi

if ! ((flag)) # Test for False
then
  : # do something
fi

flag=$((1-flag)) # Toggle flag (only works when flag is either empty or unset, 0, 1, or a string which doesn't represent a number)
```

This also works in ksh. I wouldn't be surprised if it works in all POSIX-compliant shells, but haven't checked the standard.

Comment: Does `! ! ((val))` work in Bash, like in C or C++? For example, if `val` is 0 it remains 0 after `! !`. If `val` is 1 it remains 1 after `! !`. If `val` is 8 it is pulled down to 1 after `! !`. Or do I need to ask another question?

Comment: -1 |  In POSIX sh, standalone ((..)) is undefined; please remove the reference to it

Comment: Vlastimil the question specifically is about bash - not posix shell. Why down vote when the question isn't about that topic?

Answer (score 15):

If you can be absolutely sure that the variable will contain either 0 or 1, you can use the bitwise XOR-equal operator to flip between the two values:

```
$ foo=0
$ echo $foo
0
$ ((foo ^= 1))
$ echo $foo
1
$ ((foo ^= 1))
$echo $foo
0
```

Comment: Very nice. Works only with a variable. i.e. `echo $((1 ^= 1))` didn't work.

Comment: @Artfaith: That's because of the `^=` assignment operator.  The expression `(( foo ^= 1 ))` is equivalent to `(( foo = foo ^ 1 ))`.  Your example of `((1 ^= 1))` expands to `(( 1 = 1 ^ 1 ))` which fails because you can't change the value of `1`.  To make your example work, just use the regular XOR operator `^` instead of assignment, e.g.:  `echo $(( 1 ^ 1 ))`.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
flag=false
while [[ "$flag" == "false" ]]
do
   read x
   if [[ "$x" == "true" ]]
   then
     flag=true
   fi
   echo "${x} : ${flag}"
done
```

But, actually, what you should do is replace your `while` with:

```
while ! $flag
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of a boolean variable in the shell.
Shell variables could only be `text` (an string), and, in some cases, that text may be interpreted as an integer (`1`, `0xa`, `010`, etc. ).

Therefore, a `flag=true` implies no truthfulness or falseness to the shell at all.

## String

What could be done is either a string comparison `[ "$flag" == "true" ]` or use the variable content in some command and check **its consequences**, like execute `true` (because there are both an executable called `true` and one called `false`) as a command and check if the exit code of that command is zero (successful).

```
$flag; if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then ... fi
```

Or shorter:

```
if "$flag"; then ... fi
```

If the content of a variable is used as a command, a `!` could be used to negate the exit status of the command, if an space exists between both (`! cmd`), as in:

```
if ! "$flag"; then ... fi
```

The script should change to:

```
flag=false
while ! "$flag" 
do
   read x
   if [ "$x" == "true" ]
   then
     flag=true
   fi
   echo "${x} : ${flag}"
done
```

## Integer

Use numeric values and **Arithmetic Expansions**.

In this case, the exit code of `$((0))` is `1` and the exit code of `$((1))` is `0`.
In bash, ksh and zsh the arithmetic could be carried out inside a `((..))` (note that the starting `$` is missing).

`flag=0; if ((flag)); then ... fi`

A portable version of this code is more convoluted:

```
flag=0; if [ "$((flag))" -eq 0 ]; then ... fi      # test for a number
flag=0; if [ "$((flag))"  == 0 ]; then ... fi      # test for the string "0"
```

In bash/ksh/zsh you could do:

```
flag=0    
while ((!flag)) 
do
   read x
   [ "$x" == "true" ] && flag=1
   echo "${x} : ${flag}"
done
```

## Alternatively

You can "Invert a boolean variable" (provided it contains a numeric value) as:

`((flag=!flag))`

That will **change** the value of `flag` to either `0` or `1`.

---

**Note**: Please check for errors in https://www.shellcheck.net/ before posting your code as a question, many times that is enough to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`until` is short for `while !` (and `until`, contrary to `!` is Bourne), so you can do:

```
flag=false
until "$flag"
do
   IFS= read -r x
   if [ "$x" = true ]
   then
     flag=true
   fi
   printf '%s\n' "$x : $flag"
done
```

Which should be the same as:

```
flag=false
while ! "$flag"
do
   IFS= read -r x
   if [ "$x" = true ]
   then
     flag=true
   fi
   printf '%s\n' "$x : $flag"
done
```

You could also write it as:

```
until
   IFS= read -r x
   printf '%s\n' "$x"
   [ "$x" = true ]
do
   continue
done
```

The part between the `until`/`while` and `do` doesn't have to be a single command.

`!` is a keyword in the POSIX shell syntax. It needs to be delimited, a token separated from what follows and be the first token that preceded a pipeline (`! foo | bar` negates the pipeline and `foo | ! bar` is invalid though some shells accept it as an extension).

`!true` is interpreted as the `!true` command which is unlikely to exist. `! true` should work. `!(true)` should work in POSIX-compliant shells as that `!` is delimited as it's followed by a `(` token, but in practice it doesn't work in `ksh` / `bash -O extglob` where it conflicts with the `!(pattern)` extended glob operator nor zsh (except in sh emulation) where it conflicts with `glob(qualifiers)` with `bareglobqual` and `glob(group)` without.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ ${FOO:-0} == 0 ] && FOO=1 || FOO=0
```

or even:

```
[ ${FOO:-false} == false ] && FOO=true || FOO=false
```

should do the job

Comment: You don't need the brackets: `${FOO:-false} && FOO=false || FOO=true` flips it. (This works because `true` and `false` are built-ins.)

Comment: BUt executing a variable can be 'unsafe' especially if the variable was set by a environment variable outside the script!   You best ensure variable initially set by script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```bsh
function invert_boolean() {
  if [[ "$1" == "true" ]]; then
    echo "false";
  else
    echo "true";
  fi;
}
```

And use it like this:

```bsh
VAR=false;
INVERTED=$(invert_boolean $VAR);

echo "INVERTED: $INVERTED";
# prints INVERTED: true
```

This works for both strings (eg. `"true"`) and booleans (eg. `false`).